# "WebGl 2.0 isn't available" on Firefox browser on MacBook Pro

Tags: firefox, webgl, webgl2

When i try to open a .html file i got "WebGL 2.0 isn't available". 
I'm working on MacBook Pro (late 2011) 
Firefox version: *74.0* 
Graphic card: *Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB* 
On **about:support** under **Renderer driver WebGL 2** I got this error: *WebGL creation failed: 
GL error 0x500 occurred during WebGL context initialization!* 

Could please someone help?

Comment: GL_INVALID_ENUM 0x500 can be raised for any number of reasons, Try switching browsers and or device.

Comment: You may try disabling the gpu-blacklist in about:flags, but you can't trust intel hd drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is a problem with the context creation of the canvas. It might depend by some incompatibilities between gpu and web browser. The solution found so far is to try and run the program on another browser that is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

As chrome some years ago it seems firefox has blacklisted the old macbookpro graphic card. Resulting we cannot use 3D in google maps anymore for example. In fact the machine is able to perfectly display 3D maps, as it did until firefox version 79.
I rollbacked to version 79 and can enjoy 3D again on my old but capable machine.
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/79.0b9/